# Android audio visualizer: cannot make it to work with tts

Tags: kotlin, audio, text-to-speech, visualizer

My app uses Android text-to-speech to read paragraphs, and I'd like to add an audio visualizer so to have an animation according to the speech.

I've found this [android-audio-visualizer](https://github.com/GautamChibde/android-audio-visualizer) library that looks quite interesting, but I don't know how to make it to work with tts.

In the page examples it says you have to instantiate Media player, and shows this example:

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.you_music);
```

But the fact is I'm not using MediaPlayer, but TTS for the audio. The library requires an audiosessionid to be passed to the player this way:

```
lineVisualizer.setPlayer(mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
```

But I'm not finding any way to get the audiosessionid from tts, and inspected all the properties of the TextToSpeech instance, but no getAudioSessionId() or similar is present.

```
private lateinit var ttobj: TextToSpeech
...
ttobj = TextToSpeech(this, this)
ttobj.setLanguage(Locale.US)
...
ttobj.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(object : UtteranceProgressListener() {
    override fun onStart(utteranceId: String) {
        //Here I would call setPlayer and pass an audiosessonid to start the visualizer.
    }

    override fun onDone(utteranceId: String) {
        runOnUiThread {
            ttsSpeechFinished()
        }
    }

    override fun onError(utteranceId: String) {
        Log.i("TextToSpeech", "On Error")
    }
})
...
fun doSpeech(){
    if (ttsStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
        ttobj.speak("I'm going to read a paragraph for testing, right?", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,"")
    }
}
```

The speech is working great, but I don't know how to "attach" the audio visualizer to the urrent tts audio sinthesys.

I've tried using AudioManager, that has a generateAudioSessionId() method:

```
var mAudioManager = activity?.getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
val audioSessionId = mAudioManager.generateAudioSessionId()
```

But this audioSessionId is not working, and I'm not sure I'm going in the right direction.